# Git: Clear local and remote repo and start over

Tags: git, github

I accidentally got a repo in a bad state when trying to move a project from using ant to maven. Now, I would like to clear the repo and startover from scratch. Being new to git, I am a little cautious and not sure if I could just checkout then delete all files and folders locally then push to the remote repo or if that was actually a very bad idea. For some reason I'm having a hard time asking the correct questions in google. :D

Comment: Why not just delete the repo, and then initialize it again?

Comment: just remove the `.git` dir in your local directory and do a `git push --force` to github is the solution I think.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Simply remove local `.git` directory, remove repo from server (if it is github - do Repo -> setiings -> remove).

Then create new repository on server, and locally do:

```
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/project.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: an addition this could use, and use this with caution.

`git push -u origin master --force`

Comment: @Jessycormier There's really no need for `--force` if the repository is removed from the server. It would probably overwrite the repository history if existing repository is used though.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I just wanted to refresh the local repo, I used Ruslan answer without the last two commands since I didn't need to do anything on the server side, and it worked perfectly! Of course I deleted the `.git` file locally as suggested without removing the remote directory before to execute the commands. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

To delete your repository from GitHub:

1. Go into repository `user/repoName`
2. Click on `Settings` tab

   [image]
3. At the bottom of repository page you can see `Danger Zone` section and then delete your repository
   [image]